# display message if two users are using same file in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

The problem is when I am editing one file on my pc and that same file is also being edited by next developer in next pc but when i upload the file next developers changes were lost. Is there any way to display the message that same file is being used by many users and save the changes of both?

Comment: Use a version control system like Git, Mercurial, SubVersion etc

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a version control system to manage multiple people editing the same content. Such as GIT or Mercurial

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but any api without using the Git ?

Comment: @clap No, this is what version control systems are *designed* for. Unless you're using some sort of managed environment (Sharepoint, Box, etc.) where you can lock files while you edit them, this problem is always going to happen. Git and others allow you to retain a file's history, merge changes, roll back to any previous version, and many other things. If you're developing in a team (or even individually), version control is a **must**.